# Simple ES6 promises issue - Swapped resolve and reject parameters

Tags: javascript, promise, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

Here I'd expect to see 4 and then 5 in the console. I thought that once the first `add` resolves, the `then` would go through the anonymous function, which returns another `add`.

So what am I missing that causes only the first `add` to be ran?

Fiddle: http://www.es6fiddle.net/iobmmhs3/

```
var add =  function(a, b) {
    return new Promise(function(reject, resolve) {
        console.log(a+b);
        resolve(a+b);
    });
};

add(1,3)
.then(function() {
    return add(2,3)
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `resolve` and `reject` are backwards:

```
var add =  function(a, b) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        //                      ^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^
        console.log(a+b);
        resolve(a+b);
    });
};

add(1,5)
.then(function() {
    return add(2,2)
});
```

Fiddle: http://www.es6fiddle.net/iobm7rb7/

For documentation, see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). For future reference, how you could have debugged this without knowing the signature of the function passed to the constructor: in the console, you should have seen an `Uncaught in Promise` error, which is indicating that your promise rejected, and didn't have a reject handler.

Comment: Hah, that one was staring me right in the face. Thank you!

Comment: @Elliot You can call the resolve function without parameters in your example. like `resolve()` instead of `resolve(a+b)`